# how to change color of the scrollview max stretch indicator

Tags: java, android, android-scrollview

i m creating an application in which there is a horizontal scrollview when the user scrolls the he scrollview to max length then there comes an curve like structure which can be seen in the screenshot which indicates that you have reached the max length. How can i change the color of that curve as it is blue in this application which is not looking good

[image]

Comment: Hello, I suggest you improve the question by adding a minimum working code sample

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
android:scrollbarThumbVertical="#FF94CC"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:colorEdgeEffect` for change edge color of ScrollView, RecyclerView etc.

```
<style name="HorizontalScrollViewStyle">
        <item name="android:colorEdgeEffect">@android:color/holo_green_dark</item>
</style>
```

Use this theme in your `HorizontalScrollView` :

```
  <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:theme="@style/HorizontalScrollViewStyle">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center">
                     ......
            </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

**NOTE -** `android:colorEdgeEffect` is only available for API 21 and above.